# How can I authenticate all of my (JavaScript) AJAX requests? (sending to Node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, http

I have a web app which has hundreds of HTTP requests. All of the requests go to a Node.js API that I built.

I want to be able to ensure that Node.js only responds to authenticated requests.

**So here is the problem:**  I don't want to have to go and update each and every AJAX request in my JavaScript code to include a username and password to send to the server. I began looking for a solution and I found this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ });
```

ajaxSetup allows me to set default values for future Ajax requests.

I am stuck on how to include a username and password in all requests and then read the username and password on the Node.js server?

This is what I tried:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    header: {user:'myUser', pass:'myPass'};
});
```

And on the server:

```
http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        console.log(req.headers);
........
....... 
rest of code....
```

This is what is being logged:

```
{ host: 'localhost:9000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3236.132 Safari/537.36',
  referer: 'http://localhost/skynet/app/skynet.php
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' }
```

I was hoping to be able to see my custom header, so I could use it to validate the request. But there is nothing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For starters, you'd have to add `user` and `pass` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Most people just use the [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the user and password base64 encoded, eg `Authorization: Basic bXlVc2VyOm15UGFzcwo=`

Comment: Ok, cool. I tried using authorization.. but console.log(req.headers[authorization]) returns undefined.

Comment: Well, it would be `req.headers.Authorization` or `req.headers['Authorization']` and you'd also need to add `Authorization` to your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add your custom header keys in allow headers section like

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, user, pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either through authorization header, you can just pass the base 64 encoded Eg: Authorization: bXfD23232sd through your request header
or 
the best way to send, using session_id (if it is JWT token then it may give you more secure layer) and validate that in your node server by creating a middleware, let us name it as authMiddleware

```
authMiddleware(){
    checkifJwtValid() {
        //if yes then to your controller or business logic
        //else return res.status(403).json({'err':true, 'msg':'User unauthorized'})
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using authorization.. but console.log(req.headers[authorization]) returns undefined.

Comment: did you enable authorization header in your server